# Not visible/refreshed objects or part of screen

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, scada, visual-artifacts, dvi

Do You know the situation when on screen in application you have not fully refreshed view? You need to hover the mouse on the object to make it visible/refreshed? Or You need to open close page/screen to refresh all objects?

I have PC-box with Win10. PC has only one DVI port, so extended the screens with USB to DVI adapter (3x VGA2725) and desktop is extended to 4 monitors. Each monitor is used to show the same software (SCADA) 4 different 'windows'. On the screens with adapters there is problem with view/screen refresh, like a 'artefacts' or part of screen not updated. In that situation the page needs to be closed/opened again. The CPU and disk is not overloaded.

Could You help me if above is more software issue or more hardware issue? Shell I look for bad drivers? What shall I check?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: sorry, missed the fact that the adaptor is multiplying the signal to all monitors.

Nevertheless, check with only one monitor at a time and different combinations to isolate is my suggestion.

PLEASE DISCARD THE FIRST ANSWER BELLOW..

> Has the adaptor been tested on one of the other monitors?
>
> If it has been tested on **all monitors** and the error is only on one
> of them, checking that monitor's specs, and the adaptor's specs; to
> see if there are any incompatibilities, is probably the best approach.
>
> If no testing on a different monitor has been done, I would definitely
> try to **isolate the issue by connecting the adaptor to all** external
> monitors.
>
> If you encounter the same error on a different monitor, we know it is
> most likely the adaptor, or it's drivers.